# Can I treat the expression "buenos consejos" as being singular?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

For the question

> ¿Te han dado buenos consejos tus padres?

I would like to use an affirmative answer such as "Los me han dado", but I don't know whether or not to treat "buenos consejos" as singular, despite its plurality here, and go with "Lo me han dado" instead.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that object pronouns follow the order *se - 2nd person, 1st person, 3rd person*, so you'd have *me los*

Comment: Welcome to [Spanish.SE]! Why do you think that "buenos consejos" can be treated as singular? Please explain your point of view so that we can answer more properly. The more information you give, the better we will be able to help you.

Comment: To me "buenos consejos" reads as "good advices."  Should I not take it so literal and understand that it means "good advice," but still maintain the plural?

Answer (score 1):

"buenos consejos" is plural in Spanish, unlike the non-count "advice" in English. We also have the singular "buen consejo" to refer to a single piece of advice. In a parents-children relationship, one would expect several pieces of good advice to be (or to have been) given/received. Bearing this in mind, in Spanish one would normally find your question (1) "¿Te han dado **buenos consejos** tus padres?", or:

(2) ¿Te han dado **algún buen consejo** tus padres? (Have your parents given you any good advice (i.e. throughout your life)?)

The singular indeterminate "un buen consejo" would be infrequent in questions.

The answer to (1) could be, as guifa said in a comment, "Me los han dado". An intensifier could even be used to emphasize the multiple recommendations received: "Me han dado **muchos buenos consejos**."

The answer to (2) would normaly focus on some specific advice, for example: "Sí, me aconsejaron que complete mi estudios". (Yes, they advised me to complete my education.)